# Error Pre-Release Melodic

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, pre-release

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
when I do the melodic prerelease procedureI get an error.

It also happens when I do the procedure on versions that in the past were successful

i do this:

```
mkdir -p /tmp/prerelease_job
cd /tmp/prerelease_job 

generate_prerelease_script.py   https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ros-infrastructure/ros_buildfarm_config/production/index.yaml   melodic default ubuntu bionic amd64   --custom-repo     ira_laser_tools:git:https://github.com/iralabdisco/ira_laser_tools-release.git:release/melodic/ira_laser_tools/1.0.4-1   --level` 1   --output-dir ./

./prerelease.sh
```

But now i recive this error:

```
The packages or cmake arguments have changed, forcing cmake invocation

==> Processing catkin package: 'ira_laser_tools'
==> Creating build directory: 'build_isolated/ira_laser_tools'
==> cmake /tmp/ws/src/ira_laser_tools -DCATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX=/tmp/ws/devel_isolated/ira_laser_tools -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/tmp/ws/install_isolated -DBUILD_TESTING=0 -DCATKIN_SKIP_TESTING=1 -G Unix Makefiles in '/tmp/ws/build_isolated/ira_laser_tools'
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 7.5.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 7.5.0
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/lib/ccache/cc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/lib/ccache/cc -- broken
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-3.10/Modules/CMakeTestCCompiler.cmake:52 (message):
  The C compiler

    "/usr/lib/ccache/cc"

  is not able to compile a simple test program.

  It fails with the following output:

    Change Dir: /tmp/ws/build_isolated/ira_laser_tools/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

    Run Build Command:"/usr/bin/make" "cmTC_61b2a/fast"
    /usr/bin/make -f CMakeFiles/cmTC_61b2a.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/cmTC_61b2a.dir/build
    make[1]: Entering directory '/tmp/ws/build_isolated/ira_laser_tools/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
    Building C object CMakeFiles/cmTC_61b2a.dir/testCCompiler.c.o
    /usr/lib/ccache/cc    -o CMakeFiles/cmTC_61b2a.dir/testCCompiler.c.o   -c /tmp/ws/build_isolated/ira_laser_tools/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/testCCompiler.c
    ccache: error: Failed to create directory /home/buildfarm/.ccache/tmp: Permission denied
    CMakeFiles/cmTC_61b2a.dir/build.make:65: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/cmTC_61b2a.dir/testCCompiler.c.o' failed
    make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/cmTC_61b2a.dir/testCCompiler.c.o] Error 1
    make[1]: Leaving directory '/tmp/ws/build_isolated/ira_laser_tools/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
    Makefile:126: recipe for target 'cmTC_61b2a/fast' failed
    make: *** [cmTC_61b2a/fast] Error 2




  CMake will not be able to correctly generate this project.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:2 (project)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/tmp/ws/build_isolated/ira_laser_tools/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/tmp/ws/build_isolated/ira_laser_tools/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
<== Failed to process package 'ira_laser_tools':
  Command '['cmake', '/tmp/ws/src/ira_laser_tools', '-DCATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX=/tmp/ws/devel_isolated/ira_laser_tools', '-DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/tmp/ws/install_isolated', '-DBUILD_TESTING=0', '-DCATKIN_SKIP_TESTING=1', '-G', 'Unix Makefiles']' returned non-zero exit status 1

Reproduce this error by running:
==> cd /tmp/ws/build_isolated/ira_laser_tools && cmake /tmp/ws/src/ira_laser_tools -DCATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX=/tmp/ws/devel_isolated/ira_laser_tools -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/tmp/ws/install_isolated -DBUILD_TESTING=0 -DCATKIN_SKIP_TESTING=1 -G
'Unix Makefiles'

Command failed, exiting.
# END SUBSECTION
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/347063/error-pre-release-melodic/) by [pietrocolombo](https://answers.ros.org/users/32441/pietrocolombo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 63 on 2020-03-19

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I was struggling with a similar failure, and found this issue that seems related: https://github.com/ros-infrastructure/ros_buildfarm/issues/695.

It looks like this should have been fixed by https://github.com/ros-infrastructure/ros_buildfarm/pull/696, but there hasn't been a new release in a while so maybe those changes haven't landed yet?

It seems like a workaround for now is to create the `~/.ccache` directory before running the prerelease script. Or if, as was the case for me, that directory was already created but owned by `root`, change the ownership to your user (e.g. `chown $USER:$USER ~/.ccache`). That fixed it for me.

Hope that helps.

---

Originally posted by [dpkoch](https://answers.ros.org/users/7781/dpkoch/) with karma: 132 on 2020-03-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 6

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [pietrocolombo](https://answers.ros.org/users/32441/pietrocolombo/) on 2020-03-26**:
thanks changing permissions it works

**Comment by [nickswalker](https://answers.ros.org/users/38408/nickswalker/) on 2020-07-08**:
If this resolved the issue, please mark the answer as correct.

**Comment by [suurjaak](https://answers.ros.org/users/92313/suurjaak/) on 2021-12-28**:
One and half years later, this error still persists. Putting a more detailed workaround here in case someone else gets stumped on this:

- edit `ros_buildfarm/ros_buildfarm/templates/devel/devel_task.Dockerfile.em`
- before `"USER buildfarm\nENTRYPOINT ..."`, add

  `RUN mkdir -p /home/buildfarm/.ccache`

  `RUN chown buildfarm:buildfarm /home/buildfarm/.ccache`